# Can '->to()' be used in Mojolicious::Lite?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'd like to use a moderate amount of forwarding to other controllers in a Mojolicious::Lite app.

I thought I could use `->to` ([docs](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Routes/Route#to)) do something like

```
(get '/x')->to('Route#bar');

get '/y' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render(text => 'here')
} => 'y';

app->start;
```

with code in the controller package looking like this:

```
package Route::Controller::Route;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';

sub bar {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->render(json => { hello => 'simone' });
}

1;
```

but it doesn't seem to work as `http://localhost:3000/x` returms a 404 "Page not found... yet!" and `http://localhost:3000/y` works ok

The log dump looks like this:

```
[Wed May 23 11:39:47 2018] [debug] Template "route/bar.html.ep" not found
[Wed May 23 11:39:47 2018] [debug] Template "not_found.development.html.ep" not found
[Wed May 23 11:39:47 2018] [debug] Template "not_found.html.ep" not found
[Wed May 23 11:39:47 2018] [debug] Rendering cached template "mojo/debug.html.ep"
[Wed May 23 11:39:47 2018] [debug] Rendering cached template "mojo/menubar.html.ep"
```

Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: What happens when you do that and call a route?

Comment: @simbabque - see edits

Comment: It would be super helpful if you could post relevant parts of the debug log. Mojolicious::Lite does allow `->to()` to be called (`get ...` is the same as `app->routes->get(...)`), but you have to make sure that Mojolicious finds and uses the correct controller. Note that callbacks are not a controller or controller action, so `->to('#y')` won't find anything here – consider using a separate controller class.

Comment: @amon - I added log output and separated code into a controller package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does work, if put your controller in a class and tell Mojolicious where to find that controller. By default, a Lite app does not search for controllers in any route namespaces.

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

push app->routes->namespaces->@*, 'Route::Controller';

(get '/x')->to('Route#bar');

app->start;


package Route::Controller::Route;

use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';

sub bar {
  my $self = shift;
  $self->render(json => { hello => 'simone' });
}

1;
```

When called like `perl test.pl get /x`, I see this debug output:

```
[Wed May 23 12:01:14 2018] [debug] GET "/x"
[Wed May 23 12:01:14 2018] [debug] Routing to controller "Route::Controller::Route" and action "bar"
[Wed May 23 12:01:14 2018] [debug] 200 OK (0.000467s, 2141.328/s)
{"hello":"simone"}
```

If you are fine with not using the convenient `Route#bar` syntax, you can also specify the route as:

```
get '/x' => { controller => 'Route', action => 'bar' };
```

(giving a hashref to `get` is the same as calling `->to()` on the new route with those arguments.)

Comment: that's extremely cool. Thanks. Where is "get '/x' => { controller => 'Route', action => 'bar' };" documented?Just curious.

Comment: TBH it's not clearly documented in one place, and I just read the source code instead. The `get` function in Mojo::Lite mentions that it is equivalent to `get` on the Router, which uses the `any` method, which mentions that we can use hashrefs for default stash values (in which controller and action are special stash keys).